# Reading a text file backwards and put in C

Tags: c

> I want to know how to read a text file backwards in C.

Frozen_snowman.txt is

```
Do you wanna build a snowman?
Come on lets go and play
I never see you anymore
Come out the door
It's like you've gone away-
We used to be best buddies
And now we're not
I wish you would tell me why!-
Do you wanna build a snowman?
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
```

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char buffer[100];
    char *a[100];
    FILE *f,*p;
    f=fopen("Frozen_snowman.txt","r");
    p=fopen("Reverse.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer,100,f);
        a[i]=buffer;
    }
    for(i=9;i>-1;i--)
    {
        fputs(a[i],p);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Result is

```
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
It doesn't have to be a snowman.
```

> Why is that?

Comment: Use `stegf()` rather than `fgets()`?  ;-)

Comment: You can use `fseek()` to control the position you read from in a file.  @chux: that's sooo bold. :-)

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: do you want to just reverse the characters of the line read or reverse all the characters in the file or reverse the order of the lines in the file?

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers'.  'magic' numbers make the code difficult to understand and are a headache when debugging and/or maintaining the code. some of the magic numbers are: 100, 10, 9.   Suggest using #defines or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 1):

Reason is this -

```
fgets(buffer,100,f);       // check return of fgets
a[i]=buffer;               // Note - buffer is modified in each iteration
```

You point to string which is stored in `buffer` in **last iteration**. Every pointer points to *last string read* . And each time you print same string is printed .

What you should do is *allocate memory* to pointer `a[i]` , and use `strcpy` to copy the string .

Comment: Woo pass-by-reference!

Answer (score 1):

The following code works, compiles cleanly, performs error checking, reverses the order of the lines in the input file and always cleans up after itself.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINES (100)

int main( void )
{
    int    i;

    char *a[MAX_LINES] = {NULL};  // initialize pointers for up to 100 lines
    FILE *fin = NULL;       // input file pointer
    FILE *fout = NULL;      // output file pointer

    if( NULL ==(fin=fopen("Frozen_snowman.txt","r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for input file: Frozen Snowman.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen for input successful

    if( NULL == (fout = fopen("Reverse.txt","w") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for output file Reverse.txt failed");
        fclose( fin ); // close the file opened above
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen for output successful

    // read each line into allocated memory
    // and place allocated memory pointer in array
    i = 0;
    while( i < MAX_LINES && getline(&(a[i]), NULL, fin) )
    {
        i++;
    }

    // count backwards through saved lines, printing them, then
    // returning the associated memory to the 'heap'
    for(i--; i>=0; i--)
    {
        fputs( a[i],fout);
        free( a[i] );  // no longer need this line 
    }

    // close open files before exiting
    fclose( fin );
    fclose( fout );

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's always 10 lines, you could declare a as a 2d array.

Something like this should be better.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char buffer[100];
    char a[10][100];
    FILE *f,*p;
    f=fopen("Frozen_snowman.txt","r");
    p=fopen("Reverse.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer,100,f);
        strcpy (a[i], buffer);
    }
    for(i=9;i>-1;i--)
    {
        fputs(a[i],p);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```