# First byte is not printed when using lseek

Tags: c, file, operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to output the content of a file using system calls. The code is working nice until we have a file that contains only one line. in that case, the output is the line without the first char. Where does this char get lost?

```
ssize_t rres,wres;
char buff[1];
off_t offset;
int fd = open("tester.txt",O_CREAT | O_RDWR , 0664 ); 
int line_count = 5;
for(count = 0;line_count != 0;count--){
    offset = lseek(fd, count, SEEK_END);
    rres = read(fd,buff,1);
    if(rres < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    if(*buff =='\n') line_count--;

}

count *= -1; // get abs value of bytes
count++;
while(count--){
    wres = write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,read(fd, buff,1)); // output
}
```

I am trying to output the last 5 lines of a file. But if I have less than 5 lines, the first char is not outputed.

Comment: What is that `for` loop supposed to be doing?

Comment: provide the remaining code.

Comment: Updated code, was missing one line

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This for loop is weird.

Comment: Why is `line_count != 0` commented out?

Comment: The for loop is so that I can break after i reach the 5th line from down to up

Comment: If the file has less than 5 lines, the loop will never end because you can't read 5 newlines.

Comment: You need to stop the loop if you get to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ok, step back, forget your program for the moment and tell us what you're trying to achieve. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MichaelWalz added it

Comment: How do you test less than 5 lines?  That is - when you only have one line in the file?

Comment: The file(fd) that I input is less than 5 lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[read file backwards (last line first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922829/read-file-backwards-last-line-first)
[Reading a text file backwards in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834267/reading-a-text-file-backwards-in-c)
[ading a text file backwards and put in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180537/reading-a-text-file-backwards-and-put-in-c)

Many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is reading a character from the file before it ends. If there are at least 5 lines, it reads a newline the last time, and then the rest of the code starts reading from after that newline.

But if it gets to the beginning of the file without finding 5 newlines, the last `read()` reads the first character of the file, and the rest of the code starts reading from after that.

When `*buff != '\n'` you need to print that character first.

```
if (*buff != '\n') {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, 1);
}
count *= -1; // get abs value of bytes
count++;
while(count--){
    wres = write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,read(fd, buff,1)); // output
}
```